# Selecting a React listbox value from content-script code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working with the following public web-page and trying to select a date from the listbox.

https://www.united.com/en/us/flightstatus/

The page seems to be written in React code and I'm injecting a Chrome content script (i.e. extension)  into it.

When the listbox is opened, the option items seem to be a UL followed by a bunch of LI children.

I did a `document.getElementById("li-child-id").click()` and that doesn't work.

I can force set the input field to the correct date - but when I submit the form..it uses the previously set date. So obviously I'm bypassing something.